# Replicating Master-slave on mysql using gtid in mysql-5.6

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

When replicating MySQL Master-Slave using GTID, is it necessary to set the binlog and relay_log on the slave since GTID does not depend on the binlog-file and binlog_position, and instead uses auto_position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GTID based replication binlog file and position is not needed to start the slave, but files are needed.

The process of reading binlog file and replicating commands into relay log at slave is same so that slave mysqld process can write to its own data set.